# Django login required between two servers

Tags: django, authentication

I have two servers.

Server A - this is whole bussines logic and API for mobile application.

Server B - in simply words, this is a webpage.

And now, I need to authenticate user on B but, by the 'user-data' from A. 
E.G. 
On A server I have user with loggin/password. And I need to use this same login/password on B server. There is some nice solution for that? Or just use tokens?

Answer (score 0):

*Presumed that you have an authentication mechanism in your server A.*

You have to use your server A as an Identity provider. Request to your B-server should have a session header. If this session is not valid in B-server then you have to ask for credential from the web user and forward this request to your Identity Provider(Server-A). If Server-A can identify the given credential, initiate a session in server-B for this user for a particular time frame. You have to manage this session in the Server-B.
When this user logged out from server-B just destroy the session.

Answer (score 0):

tokens should be fine such as a bearer token on the Authorization header. There are different strategies such as opaque tokens vs JWTs, etc.

I actually did a write up on API authentication tutorial and security holes:
https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/restful-apis/Authorization-on-RESTful-APIs/